# Add geolocation to Create React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, expo

I have created my first React Native app using the latest Expo CLI using instructions from [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup):

```
npm install -g expo-cli
npm expo init AwesomeProject
```

Later I wanted to add the [geolocation library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation) to this app and it seems that the whole autolinking doesn't want to work for me. I have used the provided instructions:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/geolocation
```

And I haven't done the manual linking because I am using React Native in the currently newest version (above 0.59 as said in the readme of the library). After adding the sample code:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info));
```

I have started to get errors that the library should be linked. After manually invoking the link command it still unfortunately hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually jumped out of these libraries and went full Expo on this (but i am still not sure if this is the right approach):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

export const useLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function setLocationWithPerms() {
      const permissions = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

      if (permissions.status === "granted") {
        const currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(currentLocation);
      }
    }
    setLocationWithPerms();
  }, []);

  return location;
};
```

Comment: what could be a downside of going full expo?

Comment: As for now, I don't see any. Actually I kind of grasped Expo a little bit more now and I appreciate it as a framework. But there are downsides too regarding using Expo at all - the Facebook additions make it a little bit more heavy.

Comment: Yes, I have also found expo a more scalable solution as long as you decide to develop your app with expo.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes 
Geolocation.getcurrentPosition get some error..

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: 'lat',
      longitude: 'long',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        });
      },
      (error) => alert(error),
      { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        {this.state.latitude}
         </Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        {this.state.longitude}
         </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

This is a simple demo example of geolocation. Try it out. And ask if any query.